# JasperReports Server: DB encoding issue - the Cyrillic symbols are not displaying

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm trying to run report on *JasperReports Server*. My *MySQL* db encoding is cp1251. 
The result of running report

```
� "Emika" Ltd, 3 
������� 2012
```

?- must be the Russian symbols. I found solution to set URL in report datasource

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=cp1251.
```

But it doesn't works. What I'm doing wrong?

Connection settings
 are

```
    Variable_name       Value   
character_set_client        cp1251  
character_set_connection        cp1251  
character_set_database  cp1251  
character_set_filesystem        binary  
character_set_result        cp1251  
character_set_server        cp1251  
character_set_system        utf8
```

Comment: Did you try the same report with *iReport*? Is it ok?

Comment: I had a similar problem. could you connect to your database (with a non-root user) and type "show variables like '%char%'" and post the output? I think your problem is that your client connections are forced to use some other charset (the url parameters are ignored for some reason).

Comment: @robin.koch Yes I tried to use in WHERE clause '%char%'. In don't understand how it influnce on encoding? Before it all works(rusiian symbols displayed).  And now it is works in Ireport but doesn't works on JasperServer.

Comment: @AlexК Уes it is works in Ireport without any charsetEncoding, but doesn't works on JasperReports Server

Comment: the interesting variables are character_set_client character_set_results character_set_connection, they tell you what encoding your client application receives.

Comment: @robin.koch please see my edit. This variables are on jasperserver=in ireport=in mysql db

Comment: what text font are you using? And is it available on the server? (and for jasperserver)

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem. I set the parameter init-connect="SET NAMES utf8" in file /etc/mysql/my.cnf